# Custom android IME keyboard with one button

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button, ime

I wanna create a **IME** and custom the keyboard with single button.Here is my code in `InputMethodService`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateInputView() {
    mKeyboardView = (RelativeLayout) 
                    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.input, null);
    return mKeyboardView;
}
```

And here is the layout **input.xml**

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#000000">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**But the problem is:** when I click the `EditText` on my device(already turn the system IME to mine in settings) there is a full-screen edit layout which is not relevant with `input.xml` at all.

This is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the answer by decompilation of Google's LatinIME.apk.Finally I saw a function `onEvaluateFullscreenMode()`

Yes,just override this function and return false.The custom keyboard layout won't be full-screen anymore.